# Group-specific variable tracking the last observation when a condition was met

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to construct a group-specific variable that is:

1. NA for observations until a condition is met.
2. NA for the first observation when the condition is met.
3. For subsequent observations, the value of the last prior observation when the condition was met.

Below is a MWE. I am looking for code to construct "last_value". I would much prefer to use data.table (or dplyr) for scalability/performance but am open to other suggestions. Thanks!

```
library(data.table)

data.table(
    group = c(rep("alpha", 4), rep("beta", 3)),
    time = c(1:4, 1:3),
    condition = c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No"),
    value = 1:7,
    last_value = c(NA, 1, 1, 3, NA, NA, 6))

#    group time condition value last_value
# 1: alpha    1       Yes     1         NA
# 2: alpha    2        No     2          1
# 3: alpha    3       Yes     3          1
# 4: alpha    4        No     4          3
# 5:  beta    1        No     5         NA
# 6:  beta    2       Yes     6         NA
# 7:  beta    3        No     7          6

# last_value is:

#     NA in the 1st row as that is the 1st observation for group "alpha"
#     1 in the 2nd row as the 1st observation is condition = "Yes"
#     1 in the 3rd row as the 1st observation is condition = "Yes"; 2nd observation is condition = "No"
#     3 in the 4rd row as the 3rd observation is condition = "Yes"

#     NA in the 5th row as that is the 1st observation for group "beta"
#     NA in the 6th row as there is no prior observation with condition = "Yes"
#     6 in the 7th row as the 6th observation is condition = "Yes"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took the opportunity to play with some of `data.table`'s newest additions `fifelse()` and `nafill()`:

```
DT[order(time), # necessary if data is note in order
   last_value2 := nafill(shift(fifelse(condition == "Yes", value, NA_integer_)), "locf"),
   by = group
   ]

   group time condition value last_value last_value2
1: alpha    1       Yes     1         NA          NA
2: alpha    2        No     2          1           1
3: alpha    3       Yes     3          1           1
4: alpha    4        No     4          3           3
5:  beta    1        No     5         NA          NA
6:  beta    2       Yes     6         NA          NA
7:  beta    3        No     7          6           6
```

Or with pipes:

```
DT[, 
   last_value2 := 
     fifelse(condition == "Yes", value, NA_integer_) %>% 
       shift() %>% 
       nafill("locf"),
   by = group
   ]
```

Comment: Excellent! I suggest making explicit that shift operates on time by using order(time). i.e. DT[order(time), last_value2 := nafill(shift(fifelse(condition == "Yes", value, NA_integer_)), "locf"), by = group]

Answer (score 4):

Here is another one in `dplyr` using `cummax`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(last = cummax(row_number() * (condition == "Yes")),
         last = lag(value[replace(last, last == 0, NA)]))


#  group  time condition value last_value  last
#  <fct> <int> <fct>     <int>      <dbl> <int>
#1 alpha     1 Yes           1         NA    NA
#2 alpha     2 No            2          1     1
#3 alpha     3 Yes           3          1     1
#4 alpha     4 No            4          3     3
#5 beta      1 No            5         NA    NA
#6 beta      2 Yes           6         NA    NA
#7 beta      3 No            7          6     6
```

Comment: Sir would you please be so kind to explain what does the "cummax(row_number() * (condition == "Yes")" do? I know that cummax(row_number() will keep the highest row number but the "* (condition=="yes")) are you multiplying for an "if statemen"? ? Its so awesome your code, it is the firest time I see this thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few options using `data.table`:

*1.* using non-equi join

```
DT[, lv := 
    DT[condition=="Yes"][.SD, on=.(group, time<time), x.value, by=.EACHI, mult="last"]$x.value
]
```

*2.* Cut sequences into groups where it starts with TRUE

```
DT2[, lv := if(condition[1L]) value[1L], .(group, cumsum(condition))][,
    lv := shift(lv), group]
```

*3.* Rolling join in data.table (which should be the fastest)

```
DT3[, c("lv", "t2") := .(NA_integer_, shift(time))]
DT3[group!=shift(group), t2 := NA_integer_]
DT3[, lv := DT3[(condition)][.SD, on=.(group, time=t2), roll=Inf, x.value]]
```

*4.* In the dev version of `data.table`, you should be able to use `DT[, lv2 := shift(nafill(replace(value, condition=="No", NA_integer_)), group]`. Caveat: cant test since cant upgrade.

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(
    group = c(rep("alpha", 4), rep("beta", 3)),
    time = c(1:4, 1:3),
    condition = c(T, F, T, F, F, T, F),
    value = 1:7,
    last_value = c(NA, 1, 1, 3, NA, NA, 6))
DT2 <- copy(DT); DT3 <- copy(DT);
```

output:

```
   group time condition value last_value lv
1: alpha    1      TRUE     1         NA NA
2: alpha    2     FALSE     2          1  1
3: alpha    3      TRUE     3          1  1
4: alpha    4     FALSE     4          3  3
5:  beta    1     FALSE     5         NA NA
6:  beta    2      TRUE     6         NA NA
7:  beta    3     FALSE     7          6  6
```

---

timing code:

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(0L)
ng <- 1e6
nr <- 1e7
DT <- data.table(group=sort(sample(ng, nr, TRUE)))
DT[, c("time", "condition", "value") := .(rowid(group), sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), nr, TRUE), .I)]
DT2 <- copy(DT)
DT3 <- copy(DT)

mtd0 <- function() {
    DT[, lv :=
        DT[(condition)][.SD, on=.(group, time<time), x.value, by=.EACHI, mult="last"]$x.value
    ]
}

mtd1 <- function() {
    DT2[, lv := if(condition[1L]) value[1L], .(group, cumsum(condition))][,
        lv := shift(lv), group]
}

mtd2 <- function() {
    DT3[, c("lv", "t2") := .(NA_integer_, shift(time))]
    DT3[group!=shift(group), t2 := NA_integer_]
    DT3[, lv := DT3[(condition)][.SD, on=.(group, time=t2), roll=Inf, x.value]]
}

bench::mark(mtd0(), mtd1(), mtd2(), check=FALSE)
```

timings:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 13
  expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result     memory   time  gc     
  <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>     <list>   <lis> <list> 
1 mtd0()       5.24s   5.24s    0.191      485MB    0.191     1     1      5.24s <df[,5] [~ <df[,3]~ <bch~ <tibbl~
2 mtd1()      48.55s  48.55s    0.0206     240MB    9.19      1   446     48.55s <df[,5] [~ <df[,3]~ <bch~ <tibbl~
3 mtd2()       1.28s   1.28s    0.780      618MB    0         1     0      1.28s <df[,6] [~ <df[,3]~ <bch~ <tibbl~
```

Comment: I tested all suggestions. The rolling join is by far the fastest.

Comment: The rolling join is not accurate. The value of lv in row 3 is 3 instead of 1.

Comment: Oops I think I refactored too much. The previous edit should work fine. Will change when I get back

Comment: sorry abt it. has fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `dplyr` approach, where the desired output in `last_value` is generated faithfully in `last_value2`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(value2 = if_else(condition == "Yes", value, NA_integer_)) %>%
  tidyr::fill(value2) %>%
  mutate(last_value2 = lag(value2)) %>%
  ungroup()

## A tibble: 7 x 7
#  group  time condition value last_value value2 last_value2
#  <fct> <int> <fct>     <int>      <dbl>  <int>       <int>
#1 alpha     1 Yes           1         NA      1          NA
#2 alpha     2 No            2          1      1           1
#3 alpha     3 Yes           3          1      3           1
#4 alpha     4 No            4          3      3           3
#5 beta      1 No            5         NA     NA          NA
#6 beta      2 Yes           6         NA      6          NA
#7 beta      3 No            7          6      6           6
```

Assuming the data loaded here:

```
df <- data.frame(
  group = c(rep("alpha", 4), rep("beta", 3)),
  time = c(1:4, 1:3),
  condition = c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No"),
  value = 1:7,
  last_value = c(NA, 1, 1, 3, NA, NA, 6))
```

Comment: `fill()` is not in `dplyr`?

Comment: fill is in tidyr. If you replace fill with tidyr::fill and/or load tidyr then the code works as expected. Edited response.